# How do I keep a window open in front of other windows?

Tags: gnome, window

Whenever you have multiple windows open, is there a way to keep one window on top, or at the front of the others?

Comment: What desktop manager you use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right-click on the title bar of the window and select “Always On Top”.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

In Gnome some applications (like Vivaldi browser) override the official gnome window and as the result the rightclick does not work. In these cases you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to see the window menu and then you can click the  "Always on Top" or use arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to select it.

This answer was based on [this thread](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?267758-quot-Always-on-top-quot-in-gnome3&s=ae8a6c4e1ee42819bb3c1e4afe3adf2f&p=1500781#post1500781).